# Write magic bytes to the stack to monitor its usage

Tags: c, memory-management, stack

I have a problem on an embedded device that I think might be related to a stack overflow.

In order to test this I was planning to fill the stack with magic bytes and then periodically check if the stack has overflowed by examining how much of my magic bytes that are left intact.

But I can't get the routine for marking the stack to work. The application keeps crashing instantly. This is what I have done just at the entry point of the program.

```
    //fill most of stack with magic bytes
    int stackvar = 0;
    int stackAddr = (int)&stackvar;
    int stackAddrEnd = stackAddr - 25000;
    BYTE* stackEnd = (BYTE*) stackAddrEnd;

    for(int i = 0; i < 25000; ++i)
    {
        *(stackEnd + i) = 0xFA;
    }
```

Please note that the allocated stack is larger than 25k. So I'm counting on some stack space to already be used at this point. Also note that the stack grows from higher to lower addresses that's why I'm trying to fill from the bottom and up.

But as I said, this will crash. I must be missing something here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see, you may be easily overwriting the contents of the `stackEnd` variable in the last few iterations of the loop. This is obviously a bad thing, as you're using it in the very same loop. Does stopping in your loop at, say `24900`, help?

I'd suggest to stop the loop at a well calculated value depending on the size of integer on your platform then.

Comment: So simple :) I have no idéa how I could miss that. It works perfect now. Thanks big time!

(Will accept your answer as soon as the system lets me)

Answer (score 1):

As others have already noted, you overwrite `stackEnd`. Depending on the endianness of you end up with a pointer to 0xXXXXFAFA, which is already larger (64250) than 25000 or with a pointer to 0xFAFAXXXX, which is somewhere else.

Since this is an embedded device and thus an entirely different architecture than i386, it is quite possible, that the stack grows up- instead of downwards.